# Export libraries and documents into filesystem preserving fields

Tags: export, custom-field-types, tags, file-system

I'm exporting some DOCX documents from site and subsites to filesystem, I would like to preserve:

- the site/library/file structure in the form of subfolder hierarchies
- fields (latest version, original author, custom fields, etc.) as corresponding Windows file properties (tags, etc.)

Is there any tool or should I go for a custom developed?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go for custom development, as it is free but required efforts from you.

With Open with explorer, you will not retain all the metadata and it is also slow, but you can keep the structure.

here is free tool [SPIEFolder](http://music.krichie.com/my-sharepoint-tools/#spiefolder) ( but dont maintain the metadata).

You can try couple of 3rd party tools.

[SPListX for SharePoint](http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-to-fileshare-migration/splistx/features)

[or Export & Archive Your SharePoint Content with sharegate](http://en.share-gate.com/support/tutorial-videos/archive-sharepoint-content)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that comes to mind is just opening the document library in explorer view and then copying/pasting the files/folder. As far as I know, this should retain the metadata (although thing like creation date/ author/modified date/editor may be lost). Be wary though, the explorer view uses WebDav, and will probably be quite slow during the copy. Sadly, mapping the library as a network share would be basically the same.